# How to match numeric values in NLTK feature grammar ?

Tags: nltk

The below is my grammar and it doesnt work for last production(NUM)..Can any one help me in this?  The sentense i want to parse was 'show students with number as 524'

```
S[SEM=?sp] -> SP[SEM=?sp]          
SP[SEM=(?v + ?n )] ->  V[SEM=?v] N[SEM=?n]         
SP[SEM=(?v + ?n + ?p + ?a + ?eq + ?num)] -> V[SEM=?v] N[SEM=?n] P[SEM=?p] 
A[SEM=?a] EQ[SEM=?eq] NUM[SEM=?num]

N[SEM='* FROM students'] -> 'students' | 'student'   
V[SEM='SELECT'] -> 'list' | 'show' | 'display'   
P[SEM='WHERE'] -> 'with' | 'having'  
A[SEM='id'] -> 'id' |'number'  
EQ[SEM='='] -> 'as'|'equal to'  
NUM[SEM=INT] -> INT
```